# nixops: how to use local ssh key when deploying on machine with existing nixos (targetEnv is none)?

Tags: nixops

I have machine with nixos (provisioned using terraform, [config](https://github.com/srghma/nixos-terraform-example/blob/f58934308d1d7654d73672c12197c5f8b53408da/network.tf#L1)), I want to connect to it using [`deployment.targetHost = ipAddress`](https://github.com/srghma/nixos-terraform-example/blob/f58934308d1d7654d73672c12197c5f8b53408da/network.nix#L5) and `deployment.targetEnv = "none"`

But I can't configure nixops to use `/secrets/stage_ssh_key` ssh key

This is not working ( actually this is not documented, I have found it here https://github.com/NixOS/nixops/blob/d4e5b779def1fc9e7cf124930d0148e6bd670051/nixops/backends/none.py#L33-L35 )

```
{
  stage =
    { pkgs, ... }:
    {
      deployment.targetHost = (import ./nixos-generated/stage.nix).terraform.ip;
      deployment.targetEnv = "none";

      deployment.none.sshPrivateKey        = builtins.readFile ./secrets/stage_ssh_key;
      deployment.none.sshPublicKey         = builtins.readFile ./secrets/stage_ssh_key.pub;
      deployment.none.sshPublicKeyDeployed = true;

      environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
        file
      ];
    };
}
```

`nixops ssh stage` results in asking for password, expected - login without password

`nixops ssh stage -i ./secrets/stage_ssh_key` works as expected, password is not asked

How to reproduce:

- download repo
- `rm -rf secrets/*`
- add aws keys in `secrets/aws.nix`

  `{
    EC2_ACCESS_KEY="XXXX";
    EC2_SECRET_KEY="XXXX";
  }`
- `nix-shell`
- `make generate_stage_ssh_key`
- `terraform apply`
- `make nixops_create`
- `nixops deploy` asks password

Comment: I dont use `nixops + terraform` anymore, instead plain `nixos switch + terraform`. E.g. this is my shellHook https://gist.github.com/srghma/aafd28305441e5e643be2855ef17e373