# NixOps: How to deploy to an existing NixOS VM?

Tags: linux, ssh, nix, nixos, nixops

I have almost the same problem as in this question, but it was never answered:

[nixops: how to use local ssh key when deploying on machine with existing nixos (targetEnv is none)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694551/nixops-how-to-use-local-ssh-key-when-deploying-on-machine-with-existing-nixos)

I'm not using Terraform though. Just NixOS + NixOps. So far, I:

- Created a new VM on Vultr
- Did a standard NixOS install from the current iso (20.09 pre something), setting a root password
- Enabled ssh with root password authentication and did a `nixos-rebuild switch`
- Manually generated an ssh keypair on my laptop
- `ssh`ed into the VM with the password and added the public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now I can ssh into the VM manually with the new key, as expected:

```
ssh -i .secrets/vultrtest1_rsa root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Cool. Next, I copied the existing NixOS config files to my laptop and tried to wire them up to NixOps. I tried a minimal `test1.nix`, as well as adding the `deployment."none"` and/or `users.users.root.openssh` sections below.

```
vultrtest1
├── configuration.nix
└── hardware-configuration.nix
test1.nix
```

```
# test1.nix
{
  network.description = "vultr test 1";
  network.enableRollback = true;

  vultrtest1 = { config, pkgs, ... } : {
    deployment.targetHost = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
    imports = [ ./vultrtest1/configuration.nix ];

    # deployment.targetEnv = "none"; # existing nixos vm

    # same result with or without this section:
    deployment."none" = {
      sshPrivateKey = builtins.readFile ./secrets/vultrtest1_rsa;
      sshPublicKey  = builtins.readFile ./secrets/vultrtest1_rsa.pub;
      sshPublicKeyDeployed = true;
    };

    # same result with or without this:
    users.users.root.openssh.authorizedKeys.keyFiles = [ ./secrets/vultrtest1_rsa.pub ];
  };

}
```

In all cases, when I try to create and deploy the network NixOps tries to generate another SSH key, then fails to log in with it:

```
$ nixops create test1.nix -d test1
created deployment ‘b4ac25fa-c842-11ea-9a84-00163e5e6c00’
b4ac25fa-c842-11ea-9a84-00163e5e6c00

$ nixops list
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------------------+------------+------+
| UUID                                 | Name  | Description            | # Machines | Type |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------------------+------------+------+
| b4ac25fa-c842-11ea-9a84-00163e5e6c00 | test1 | Unnamed NixOps network |          0 |      |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------------------+------------+------+

$ nixops deploy -d test1                                                             
vultrtest1> generating new SSH keypair... done
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
vultrtest1> could not connect to ‘root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX’, retrying in 1 seconds...
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
vultrtest1> could not connect to ‘root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX’, retrying in 2 seconds...
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
vultrtest1> could not connect to ‘root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX’, retrying in 4 seconds...
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
vultrtest1> could not connect to ‘root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX’, retrying in 8 seconds...
root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/bin/..nixops-wrapped-wrapped", line 991, in <module>
    args.op()
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/bin/..nixops-wrapped-wrapped", line 412, in op_deploy
    max_concurrent_activate=args.max_concurrent_activate)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 1063, in deploy
    self.run_with_notify('deploy', lambda: self._deploy(**kwargs))
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 1052, in run_with_notify
    f()
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 1063, in <lambda>
    self.run_with_notify('deploy', lambda: self._deploy(**kwargs))
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 996, in _deploy
    nixops.parallel.run_tasks(nr_workers=-1, tasks=self.active_resources.itervalues(), worker_fun=worker)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/parallel.py", line 44, in thread_fun
    result_queue.put((worker_fun(t), None, t.name))
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 979, in worker
    os_release = r.run_command("cat /etc/os-release", capture_stdout=True)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/backends/__init__.py", line 337, in run_command
    return self.ssh.run_command(command, self.get_ssh_flags(), **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/ssh_util.py", line 280, in run_command
    master = self.get_master(flags, timeout, user)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/ssh_util.py", line 200, in get_master
    compress=self._compress)
  File "/nix/store/kybdy5m979h4kvswq2gx3la3rpw5cq5k-nixops-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/ssh_util.py", line 57, in __init__
    "‘{0}’".format(target)
nixops.ssh_util.SSHConnectionFailed: unable to start SSH master connection to ‘root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX’
```

What am I missing? Perhaps I can manually add the key NixOps just generated?

Update: I used [SQLiteBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to look inside the NixOps state database and pasted the generated public key into `authorized_keys`. Now I can `ssh` in with the newly generated key manually, but NixOps still fails to deploy.

Comment: do you have your configuration files available? perhaps in github, I'll see if i can recreate?

Comment: Sure. I just figured out a partial solution by adding the key to `~/.ssh/config` so no urgency. Do you still want them? It'll take me a few minutes to remove the `.nixops` file (with private keys) from the bitbucket history and mark it public.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/jefdaj/knlab-nixops

EDIT: You might have a better time with a commit from before I started adding my other code as submodules: https://bitbucket.org/jefdaj/knlab-nixops/commits/3cbb47b19a67dd328561c90fb503622fadf618be

Comment: Just a friendly note to NOT run nixos-rebuild after nixops else things break. They did for me at least.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it temporarily, in a not-very-satisfying way:

- browsed the database for the public + private key NixOps generated
- manually added those to `authorized_keys` on the VM
- also added the old key to the local `~/.ssh` with an entry in `~/.ssh/config`

No idea why NixOps uses the local ssh config, or how to prevent that. The entry that works looks like:

```
Host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  HostName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  Port 22
  User root
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vultrtest1_rsa
```

Will wait a couple days, then mark this as the solution unless anyone can explain how to tell NixOps to use the local key from `.secrets` instead of `~/.ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source at

https://github.com/NixOS/nixops/blob/master/nix/options.nix

there is  deployment.provisionSSHKey option

which says.

```
  deployment.provisionSSHKey = mkOption {
  type = types.bool;
  default = true;
  description = ''
    This option specifies whether to let NixOps provision SSH deployment keys.
    NixOps will by default generate an SSH key, store the private key in its state file,
    and add the public key to the remote host.
    Setting this option to <literal>false</literal> will disable this behaviour
    and rely on you to manage your own SSH keys by yourself and to ensure
    that <command>ssh</command> has access to any keys it requires.
  '';
};
```

Maybe this can help? Once i'll get back to my Nixops machine, I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's helpful but not yet in the release version.